# No-variable array index assignment

Tags: php, arrays, syntax

I recently wrote this code:

```
// $day =  1..31
$ends = ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd'];
$day .= ($day%10 < 4 ? $ends[$day%10] : 'th');
```

Why can't I write: (?)

```
$day .= ($day%10 < 4 ? ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd'][$day%10] : 'th');
```

Is it possible to use array which is not in variable?

**EDIT:**
Is it possible in PHP 5.5?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php: _“As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable.”_ Btw., even that considered your code is still incorrect, because automatic array index starts at 0, so if your day is 3 it will fail as well.

Comment: @CBroe would the fix be ['','st','nd','rd']?

Comment: Isn't that possible? Are you certain that `$day` is a defined integer value? Which error are you getting?

Comment: What about the 21st, 22nd, 23rd & 31st of the month?

Comment: @scunliffe thx for notice, I'm low level in english ..

Comment: @CBroe _„As of PHP 5.5 it is possible to array dereference an array literal.“_ means that in 5.5 is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
$ends = ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd'];
```

It should be:

```
$ends = Array ('th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd');
```

Your code wasn't running at all. It was failing before executing with the message

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in Your Code`

You may not have errors turned on in your PHP installation, so you weren't aware of that. You can't define arrays in PHP like you can in Javascript. Once I made the above change, your code ran fine.

And your algorithm seems to work as well, though I didn't test it for every single number from 1 to 31.

P.S. You cannot do this:

```
$day .= ($day%10 < 4 ? Array ('th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd')[$day%4] : 'th');
```

And you should be glad because it looks pretty ugly. :)

Comment: In 5.5 It's possible to define an array on the fly: $Arr [ ..,..,..];

Comment: @Daryl Gill Yes, my bad... serves me right for being too lazy to upgrade my personal installation. Still, even under 5.5, I don't think he can do this:
$day .= ($day%10 < 4 ? ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd'][$day%4] : 'th');

Comment: Doesn't your algorithm allow 11st, 12nd, 13rd? You should add a check to see if `$day < 11 && $day > 19`. Also, using `["a", "b", "c"][1]` works for me.

Comment: @RobertSF My question was _Why can't I write?_ and your answer: _You cannot do this_. 
Very useful ...

Comment: @marek094 I am sorry, Marek. I didn't mean to be unhelpful. I thought the design of the language just didn't allow it, but it seems that I was wrong. Max above says that it does work.